# SBT doesn't see Java classes

Tags: java, scala, import, sbt

This is how my directories tree looks like:

```
src/main/ --- java (some .java files)
          |
          |- scala (subdirectories with .scala files)
          |
          |- resources (some images)
```

I try to import a package which is written in Java into my Scala project.

```
[error] /home/ciembor/test/src/main/scala/TestView.scala:9: not found: object waveform
[error] import waveform._
[error]        ^
```

I think sbt doesn't browse through files from src/main/java. How may I force it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `src/main/java`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are your java files in the proper directories, e.g., src/main/java/waveform/...?

Unlike scala, java file hierarchies are supposed to match their packaging. Scala/sbt will make this happen for scala files but not for java files.

Comment: That's it! They were directly in /src/main/java/